# How to get ultra smooth BLDC velocity control (Netflix robotic project)

Tags: robotic-arm, brushless-motor

We've been working on this for quite some time, let me share what we have tried:

- Multiple motors (skewed magnet, 24 pole, [in-runner](https://store.cubemars.com/goods-859-RI100+KV105.html), outrunner)
- Multiple encoders (14-bit optical, 40K CPR optical, 19-bit magnetic RLS)
- Multiple motor drives (odrive, mjbots)

  - Tuned control https://docs.odriverobotics.com/v/latest/control.html
- Anti cogging algorithms

Our issue is that no matter what we do, we can't get velocity smoothness < 0.1 rev/s. Especially at speeds 5RPS +, at low speeds velocity is quite smooth with high-resolution encoders.

Our application requires ultra-smooth controls for automatic camera operations.

Any idea why we can't get smoothness < 0.1 RPS ??

Here is what our velocity looks like:
[image]

Comment: Some aspects that may be relevant to the final performances are: (1) how the speed is reduced via a gearbox; (2) if the encoder is installed on the fast or slow shaft or on both; (3) the type of the controller (e.g., PID vs. MPC); (4) the type of speed estimator (e.g., frequency-based filter, EKF, UKF).

Comment: An open-source article on this topic: https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/20/5/1526. The speed they claim to track is about 10 deg/s.

Comment: To complement the citation above: a BLDC is a type of PMSM but shows more torque ripples than a BLAC (a PMSM with sinusoidal back-emf) because of the typical 6-step actuation; the latter is thus easier to control at low speed.

Comment: @UgoPattacini No reducer in this setup and controls is cascaded PID

Comment: Not having a speed reducer may be problematic. BLDC motors are designed to run at high speed per se to transform speed in torque via a reducer.

Comment: @UgoPattacini Eventual system will have 100:1 harmonic reducer, but right now we're getting the baseline motor only system smoother.

Comment: With the 100:1 reducer, the system will change its characteristics outright. It'll be beneficial also for velocity estimation.